# How to adjust UI with collapsed controls in Xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

My project is for WP8.1 and i'm using Silverlight.
In this project, I have two rectangles, a blue and a red one. I want each one to take 50% of the screen width so i made this :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Blue" Visibility="{Binding BlueRectVisibility}" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Red" Visibility="{Binding RedRectVisibility}"/>
</Grid>
```

Sometime, one of this rectangles can have his visibility set to Collapsed by binding. What i want then is the other one to take all the width.
With that Xaml, the visible rectangle just take half of the screen.

Changing the ColumnDefinitions to Auto does not work because the Grid does not take 100% of the screen width anymore.

Can you please explain how to make a "dynamic" UI doing that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `Auto` doesn't work is because the layout goes something like this:

1. `Page`: Hey `Grid`, how big do you want to be?
2. `Grid`: Dunno, lemme ask `ColumnDefinition`. How big do you wanna be?
3. `ColumnDefinition`: Gee, I'm not sure; I need to ask `Rectangle`. Hey `Rectangle`, how much space do you need?
4. `Rectange`: Eh, I don't really care.
5. `ColumnDefinition`: Zero it is then!
6. *And so on back up the chain*

So you end up with a zero-width column. The solution is to bind the widths dynamically. [@Tam Bui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32055211/4184842) has the right approach, but here is a simplified version for Windows Phone 8.1:

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
  <Grid Height="100">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding FirstColumnWidth}" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding SecondColumnWidth}"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Blue" />
    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Grid.Column="1"/>
  </Grid>
  <Button Content="toggle column width" Click="ToggleColWidth"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  GridLength firstWidth;
  GridLength secondWidth;

  public MainPage()
  {
    firstWidth = secondWidth = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
  {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public GridLength FirstColumnWidth
  {
    get { return firstWidth; }
    set { firstWidth = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
  }

  public GridLength SecondColumnWidth
  {
    get { return secondWidth; }
    set { secondWidth = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
  }

  private void ToggleColWidth(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (FirstColumnWidth.GridUnitType == GridUnitType.Star)
    {
      FirstColumnWidth = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Pixel);
      SecondColumnWidth = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
    else
    {
      FirstColumnWidth = SecondColumnWidth = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
  }
}
```

With this approach, you don't even need to change the `Visibility` of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of the problem is that you are defining the Grid's Columns to be 50%, so once that's established, then changing the visibility of the Rectangle will not make any difference.  I made this small POC using WPF (not sure if all of the commands translate to Silverlight, but you can try it).  Basically I focus on messing with the Column's width instead of the Rectangle visibility.

In your xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="CollapsibleRegion.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CollapsibleRegion"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="B" Command="{Binding ToggleWidthCommand}" CommandParameter="Blue"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="R" Command="{Binding ToggleWidthCommand}" CommandParameter="Red"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="blueColumn" Width="{Binding BlueColumnWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="redColumn" Width="{Binding RedColumnWidth}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Red" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

In your code-behind (xaml.cs):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private GridLength blueColumnWidth;

    private GridLength redColumnWidth;

    private ToggleWidthCommand toggleWidthCommand;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.BlueColumnWidth = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star);
        this.RedColumnWidth = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public GridLength BlueColumnWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return this.blueColumnWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            this.blueColumnWidth = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public GridLength RedColumnWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return this.redColumnWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            this.redColumnWidth = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ToggleWidthCommand ToggleWidthCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.toggleWidthCommand == null)
            {
                this.toggleWidthCommand = new ToggleWidthCommand(this);
            }

            return this.toggleWidthCommand;
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, for the ToggleWidthCommand.cs, add this:

```
public class ToggleWidthCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainWindow parent;

    public ToggleWidthCommand(MainWindow parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var blueOrRed = (string)parameter;

        if (blueOrRed == "Blue")
        {
            if (this.parent.BlueColumnWidth.Value == 0)
                this.parent.BlueColumnWidth = new System.Windows.GridLength(5, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Star);
            else
                this.parent.BlueColumnWidth = new System.Windows.GridLength(0, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Pixel);
        }
        if (blueOrRed == "Red")
        {
            if (this.parent.RedColumnWidth.Value == 0)
                this.parent.RedColumnWidth = new System.Windows.GridLength(5, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Star);
            else
                this.parent.RedColumnWidth = new System.Windows.GridLength(0, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Pixel);
        }
    }
}
```

This was just a proof-of-concept, so obviously there are more efficient/cleaner/expandable ways to implement this behavior, but I was just trying to whip up a response quickly to show you how it can be done.  Hope it works for you!